# Can you insert multiple attachments to iMessage with insertAttachment call?

Tags: ios, imessage

I'm building an iOS app with an iMessage extension.  I am successfully using the insertAttchment call from within the iMessage app to attach a media file to a text message for the user to send, however, I would like to attach two or three attachments at one time, before the user taps send.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how it would be accomplished?

Here is the code I successfully use to attach one media file:

```
func didClickItem(_ controller: ItemViewController, itemUrl: URL) {
    if let conversation = self.activeConversation {
        conversation.insertAttachment(itemUrl, withAlternateFilename: "", completionHandler: nil)

    }
```